# How to install Brosix secure instant messaging on an Aquaris E5 Ubuntu phone

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-touch, dpkg, aquaris

I have already installed the Brosix .deb app on my Kubuntu 15.04 laptop without any problems.
I copied the app to the downloads folder on my Aquaris E5 Ubuntu touch phone, downloaded the terminal from the Ubuntu store and used the 'sudo apt-get install' command in an attempt to install the app.
I receive the following message(s)...

W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock

E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt

E: The package list or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Does anyone know how to sucessfully add Brosix to an ubuntu phone?

I chose Brosix due to the security aspect and the fact that it can be installed on all platforms, so I'm really hoping there is a solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Brosix is providing versions for amd64 and i386 processors. This means 64bit and 32bit desktops.

Phones are using ARM processors.

So, at least they should recompile for armhf (and also make sure that the application doesn't depend on X11 display server).

Comment: Thanks for your response Velkan, apologies for the overdue reply.
I decided to use Brosix via the Browser...less hassle but the downside is, no video calls only text.